# Subplotting Mysql data with Python

Tags: python, mysql, matplotlib

I use this code to make charts which appear on the same chart here. I'd like to make them on separate charts/ subplots. How can I do this? There are many examples but most of them are either with csv files or random numbers. I couldn't find a good plotting tutorial with mysql in this case. Thanks.

```
import mysql.connector
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas

# connect to MySQL database 
conn = mysql.connector.MySQLConnection(user='root', password='',
                              host='127.0.0.1', database='DB')

query = """SELECT Time, Stag, Mean, Diff, Var, Ment, Med FROM Maintab;"""

df = pandas.read_sql(query, conn, index_col=['Time'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df=df.astype(float)
df.plot(ax=ax)
conn.close()
```

With some trials, I got this so far:

```
import mysql.connector
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

# connect to MySQL database 
conn = mysql.connector.MySQLConnection(user='root', password='',
                              host='127.0.0.1', database='DB')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT Time, Stag, Mean, Diff FROM Maintab');
rows = cursor.fetchall()
#print(rows)

df = pd.DataFrame( [[ij for ij in i] for i in rows] )
df.rename(columns={0: 'Time', 1: 'Stag', 2: 'Mean', 3: 'Diff'}, inplace=True);
df = df.astype('int')
df["Time"] = df['Time'].astype('int')
df["Stag"] = df['Stag'].astype('int')
df["Mean"] = df['Mean'].astype('int')
df["Diff"] = df['Diff'].astype('int')


plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.title('Stag')
plt.plot(df["Time"],'b-',label=r'$T_1$')
plt.plot(df['Stag'],'g:',label=r'$T_2$')
plt.legend(loc='best')



plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.title('Mean')
plt.plot(df["Time"],'b-',label=r'$T_1$')
plt.plot(df['Mean'],'g:',label=r'$T_2$')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

and which gives me this result:

[image]

Comment: could you show what the `df` looks like?

Comment: Did you ask this question twice by accident? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52947344/subplotting-mysql-data-with-python

Comment: yes, i wasn't aware of it. I deleted the other post now. thanks.

Comment: You can just use the same plotting code as the examples. Once the data is loaded into a dataframe all the plotting should be the same

Comment: onno, time is actually serial numbers starting from 1,2,3 etc. the others are digits.